# XmlTextReader doesnt not recognize the self enclosing tag XML node

Tags: c#, xml

`XmlTextReader` -> `XmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement`

The above written does not return true case of Self enclosing Element Like:

```
<Default Name= "One"/>
```

Can any body tell the alternate solution for it. I am able to achieve the desired result by using the `XmlTextReader.IsEmptyElement` property.

Is there any other way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Note, the correct term is "self-closing".

Answer (score 1):

As the given example is *not* an end element, but *is* an empty element your found solution is the correct one. So maybe just check for both cases to get your desired condition:

```
if (XmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement || XmlTextReader.IsEmptyElement)
```